# unable to see my anything in database pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I really am at a loss here. I am using Pycharm 5.0.4 and running a virtual env with Python3 and Django 2.0.1.

I am trying to get my database up and running for my project, but no matter what I do I cannot seem to get anything to show up in the database tool window drop down in Pycharm. I have `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'` set in my `settings.py`, and in Pycharm i am going to:

 Create New -> Data Source -> SQlite(Xerial).

I then `makemigrations` and `migrate` but nothing shows up in the database. I can even go to the project website and succesfully add/create models in the admin site. But I cannot figure out where they are or see them...

It was working at one point but I deleted my database because I was getting some errors and now I am trying to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to go to Create New -> Data Source -> SQlite(Xerial). 
if your setting.py database config is as is (`'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'`)  the database is autogenerated when you run makemigrations  then migrate.

to recreate the database (you said you deleted):

1. remove previous migrations (delete all files in your app's migration folder except the **init**.py)
2. `Ctrl+Alt+R` (or tools -> run manage.py)
3. then in the manage.py terminal run `makemigrations and`migrate`

a new database will be created and migrations applied......... you dont have to worry about seeing the entries in the database directly.

If you're able to `create superuser` and login to the admin site and manipulate model data, then you're up and running

Comment: hello, i tried this several times. I agree that my database is somewhere, but why can i not see it in the side panel like i used to be able to?

Comment: so i right clicked on the database that Pycharm shows in the project directory (assuming that is the auto generated one) and selected `As Data Source..`, then clicked yes a couple of times and the database showed up in the "Database" panel with the correct tables

Comment: Oh.... You must have accidentally closed the database view.     good to know you're up and running now